# How to block all traffic to my server that are connecting using my IP instead of my domain name?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, iptables

I have fedora server, i want any connection to use my server domain name or otherwise be blocked.. I don't mind if i use iptables (or csf) or if not then through apache configs.

Comment: That's not possible on an IP basis, there are only few protocols that support this.

Comment: It sounds like you might be using cPanel. In this case the existing answers will not help you, you should not attempt to use them, and you should contact cPanel support. We cannot support cPanel and similar systems here.

Comment: i dont use cPaner @MichaelHampton

Comment: and the suggested [answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/457158/request-of-a-domain-with-no-virtualhost-in-apache-ends-to-default-virtualhost) is not related to my question at all..

Comment: @MHMr It is the answer to the question you posted above. Do you have some other question?